# Floating Action Button colour

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I am using one of the preset button designs (an add button) for my FAB. I was able to change the colour of the background colour of the button but the plus is green and I want to change that. How can I change that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using

> android:tint

property you can set the color like this

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:tint="@android:color/white"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />
```

---

Hope this helps. Good luck :)